# OAuth Error: Invalid client and Bad Bad client credentials

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

I am doing about spring security oauth2. But when i login it always notice:

> OAuth Error
>   error="invalid_client", error_description="Bad client credentials".

I followed many same questions on stack overflow but haven't fixed this.

This is my AuthorizationServerConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@PropertySource("application.properties")
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {

        security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients
            .inMemory()
            .withClient("ClientId")
            .secret("secret")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code")
            .scopes("user_info")
            .autoApprove(true)
            .redirectUris("http://localhost:8000");
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        final TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(tokenEnhancer()));
  endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore()).tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain).authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
```

ResourceServerConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ResourceServerConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService; 

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.requestMatchers()
            .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .permitAll();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

       auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

CustomUserDetailsService class:

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UsersRepository usersRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        Optional<Users> usersOptional = usersRepository.findByName(username);

        usersOptional
            .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found!"));
        return usersOptional
            .map(CustomUserDetails::new)
            .get();
    }
}
```